# Dynamically deploy web application from puppet master to subset of puppet agents

Tags: puppet

I don't want to hardcode nodes and modules in site.pp, I want to get the list of modules from database when agent poll the configuration.

I have lists of agents in MSSQL database and I want to deploy web applications to these lists.

Now I have different modules for different agents,

forexample, this is my data in database

Server      Module
A   Product
B   Product
A   Employee
C   Employee
D   Employee

I want to deploy Product web to server: A,B  and Employee web to server: A,C,D

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at implementing an [External Node Classifier (ENC)](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html). You would need to create a script that reads from the database and returns YAML for the calling node. This will allow you to not use the `site.pp` file at all and manage configuration from your database. 
There are some caveats on how it's used though, so be sure it meets your needs.